# warning: Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, elf

**ENV**

fedora 29 x86_64

gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)

**code**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    int n; 

    for (n=0; n<10; n++) {
       printf("Print Number: %d\n";, n); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

*compile*:

```sh
gcc h.c -o h.g -g
```

And I also tried `-fcf-protection=full`, follow [this link](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-March/121951.html).

```sh
gcc h.c -o h.bg -fcf-protection=full -g
```

**Problem**

When using `gdb ./h.g` or `gdb ./h.bg`, I got `warning: Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments`.

the result of `readelf`:

```sh
[user@localhost myctest]$ readelf --segments h.g | tail -n 14

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt 
   03     .init .plt .text .fini 
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   06     .dynamic 
   07     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   08     .eh_frame_hdr 
   09     
   10     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got 
[user@localhost myctest]$ readelf --segments h.bg | tail -n 15

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.gnu.property .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt 
   03     .init .plt .plt.sec .text .fini 
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   06     .dynamic 
   07     .note.gnu.property 
   08     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   09     .eh_frame_hdr 
   10     
   11     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

We can see that `.note.gnu.property` exists in file h.bg, but it still gets warning.

[DOC: (warning-loadable-section-my-section-outside-of-elf-segments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508277/warning-loadable-section-my-section-outside-of-elf-segments) does not have solution.

**EDIT**

I put `readelf --all` output to codepad. [h.g](http://codepad.org/jzBZffQW), [h.bg](http://codepad.org/4L3ubkUd).

I am confused about this. Any clues to remove the warning? Thank you.

Comment: Please show the _entire_ `readelf` output -- you've cut the most important parts out.

Comment: I put `readelf --all` output to codepad. [h.g](http://codepad.org/jzBZffQW), [h.bg](http://codepad.org/4L3ubkUd).

Comment: @EmployedRussian any advice for this?