# warning: Loadable section "ER_RW" outside of ELF segments

Tags: arm, gdb, vscode-debugger, keil, segger-jlink

I have build an elf file using the arm compiler v5.03 for Cortex-M3 Processor (STM32F105). The keil/Lauterbach/Ozone debugger are able to use this elf and program the device and start debug sessions with out any issues.

I am trying to use GDB client with J-Link GDB server using visual studio code to program and start debugging but it is failing. when I run the arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe on the elf file I am getting "Warning: Loadable section "ER_RW" outside of ELF segments".

Its sounds like the keil/ozone could figure out the addresses from ELF file but its not compatible with GDB client.

Any ideas?

I tried to follow the steps from this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508277/warning-loadable-section-my-section-outside-of-elf-segments" but I get "arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe: cannot open: C:\ExampleProject....\ExampleProject.bin: Permission denied".

I am not sure what is causing this issue, I ran the command prompt in administrator mode and changed the permissions of all the folders.